# non-case-sensitive version of file exists command

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

Well, not sure what to do in this regard.  A little while ago I modified a logging script for an eggdrop bot.. but now an issue unfolds that for some reason, it is logging actions/text in separate files because of an issue of character case.  `#channel.html` exists, as does `#Channel.html`, though the former is written to because of the current state of the channel name(it can change if all users leave and one rejoins with different case).

I've narrowed this problem down to what I believe is the issue.  `file exists 'filename_here'`.  I've looked through tcl's documentation, and I've read through the wiki regarding mixed case file names(it treats them as different files of course), but I have yet to find such an option(or user made proc) that would allow me to disable this behavior.

Is there a way around/to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the file system (i.e., the OS) as [`file exists`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M15) is just a thin wrapper around the OS's basic file existence test. Classic Unix filesystems are mostly case-sensitive, whereas Windows filesystems are usually case-insensitive. This means that it is usually best to write your code to be careful with handling the case of things; you probably ought to consider using [`string tolower`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M44) to get a channel name in an expected case (since I think IRC channel names are case-insensitive).

But if you can't do that, the best you can do is to get the list of filenames that match case-insensitively and check if that's a single value. Alas, this is a messy operation as [`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm) doesn't have a `-nocase` option (it's rare that people want such a thing), so we need to use [`string match -nocase`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) to help out:

```
set files [lmap f [glob *.html] {
    expr {[string match -nocase ${channel}.html $f] ? $f : [continue]}
}]
if {[llength $files] == 1} {
    set channel_file [lindex $files 0]
} else {
    # Oh no! Ambiguity!
}
```

That uses [`lmap`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm) from Tcl 8.6; earlier versions of Tcl should use this instead:

```
set files {}
foreach f [glob *.html] {
    if {[string match -nocase ${channel}.html $f]} {
        lappend files $f
    }
}
if {[llength $files] == 1} {
    set channel_file [lindex $files 0]
} else {
    # Oh no! Ambiguity!
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I don't have any doubts that this will work, however I'm holding off on accepting because I haven't had a chance to attempt implementation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a filename case (#channel.html, #Channel.html or #CHANNEL.HTML) and use [string tolower](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M44), [string totitle](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M45) or [string toupper](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M46) respectively on `filename_here`. Then use that value for all file operations.

Answer (score 1):

An **lsearch** filter on **glob** can be used to perform a case-insensitive search for a particular file name, e.g.

```
% lsearch -nocase -all -inline -glob [glob ./*] {*/myfile.txt}
./myFile.txt ./Myfile.txt ./MYFILE.txt
```

A sanity check using **llength** on the lsearch result above can be used to flag an error in case more than one file name is returned.